# Create rows for missing months in data grouped by year and month (multi index)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas-groupby

I want to get average monthly total precipitation based on wind direction restriction. I group my data by year and month but do to the wind direction restriction some months are thrown out of the index. However, I need to force these months back into the index to be able to reshape the data frame (12 months for every years) and plot heat maps. For instance, in year 1995, December (month 12) is missing from the multi index. [How to add it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT16m.png)?

```
walney_day = walney_wff.set_index(['year', 'month', 'day']).sum(level=[0,1,2]).reset_index()

#identifying dry days:
walney_day['dry'] = np.where((walney_day['precp']==0), 1, 0).copy()

#grouping by month to get a monthly count of the dry days:
walney_month = walney_day.groupby([walney_day['year'], walney_day['month']]).sum()
```

Comment: Can you also provide an example or sample of the data so that it can be reproduced easily in the future?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I just editing my question and added a screenshot illustrating my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Actually I found a solution to my problem. It involves the following steps:
1) instead of using .groupby(year, month) and get a multi index, I use .set_index(['year', 'month']).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index() so that my group index does not involve datetime variables.

2) I create a 'date' column from the "year" and "month" columns, I used to group my date, using: pd.to_datetime(walney_month[['year', 'month']].assign(day=1)) ##Note: I need to assign a day (here, each monthly values are associated with the first day of the month).

3) I use that 'date' column as new index for my dataset using:.set_index('date')

4) I get the complete list of months in my my date range using: pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='MS') ##Note: I used 'MS' to all each element of the list to be the first day of each month in the range.

5) I reindex my dataframe using the date list obtained from 4) using: .reindex()

Here is my code:

```
walney_day = walney_wff.set_index(['year', 'month', 'day']).sum(level [0,1,2]).reset_index()

walney_day['dry'] = np.where((walney_day['precp']==0), 1, 0).copy()

walney_month = walney_day.set_index(['year', 'month']).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index()

walney_month['date'] = pd.to_datetime(walney_month[['year', 'month']].assign(day=1))

walney_month = walney_month.set_index('date')

all_months = pd.date_range(walney_month.index.min(), walney_month.index.max(), freq='MS')

walney_month = walney_month.reindex(all_months)
```

[output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbNTN.png).